# Convert date object to string in boost

Tags: boost, date, format

Using the boost library how would I convert a date object:

```
 date d(2010,10,01);
```

to a string with the format: DD-mmm-YYYY, so that variable 
d would become "01-Oct-2010".

Now there are number of functions for converting a date object to a 
string such as

```
 std::string to_simple_string(date d)
```

which returns a string in the format YYYY-mmm-DD. But I was unable 
to find the format I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_facet) about date facet? The example appears like it should work for your scenario.

```
//example to customize output to be "LongWeekday LongMonthname day, year"
//                                  "%A %b %d, %Y"
date d(2005,Jun,25);
date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%A %B %d, %Y"));
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
std::cout << d << std::endl;
// "Saturday June 25, 2005"
```